# get exact file path as before on newer android versions with getExternalStoragePublicDirectory?

Tags: android, image, file, kotlin, mediastore

i am trying to get the path like this.

```
val storageDir = File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "Tackle Box"
        )
```

and it is depricated and I tried

```
getExternalFilesDir()
```

but it is not returning the correct path and the images are not displayed.

I just cant wrap my head around the MediaStore method to get the same path as stated above.

Thank you for your time

Comment: "and it is depricated" -- FWIW, it is undeprecated in Android 12L and should remain so going forward. I received word from Google that `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is safe to use.

Comment: ok, wow, thank you @CommonsWare, it just has that line through it and its driving me crazy trying to do an update. It was working on my Android 12 Pixel 5 and im just thinking, "should i even change this?"

Comment: Note that just because it is undeprecated does not mean that it necessarily works as it did before. For example, you still cannot create arbitrary directories off of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. It is just that it is safe to use those methods, despite the now-current deprecation warning.

Comment: @CommonsWare, good to know. Life is beautifull!

Comment: @CommonsWare, thank you for info!